# Cloudinary uploader.upload executed after next async command in file

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload file with `Multer` and `cloudinary node.js api` and then remove temp file from hard drive, however file gets deleted before upload finished. Then I commented `unlink` files uploaded correctly

Here is my controller

```
const createGame = async (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        use_filename: true,
        unique_filename: false,
        overwrite: true,
    };
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        const files = req.files;
        let posterPath = "";
        let videoPath = "";
        let distroPath = "";
        if (files?.poster?.length) {
            posterPath = files?.poster[0]?.path || "";
            try {
                const newPath = await uploader.upload(posterPath, options);
                // Bug - unlink happens before file uploaded
                await unlink(posterPath);
                posterPath = newPath as string;
            } catch (err) {
                // Upload failure - remove files from disk
                await unlink(posterPath);
                posterPath = "";
            }
        }
        if (files?.video?.length) {
            videoPath = files?.video[0]?.path || "";
            try {
                const newPath = await uploader.upload(videoPath, {
                    ...options,
                    resource_type: "video",
                });
                // Bug - unlink happens before file uploaded
                await unlink(videoPath);
                videoPath = newPath as string;
            } catch (err) {
                // Upload failure - remove files from disk
                await unlink(videoPath);
                videoPath = "";
            }
        }

        const currentPublisher = await publishersRepository.findOneBy({
            id: req.user.id,
        });

        if (!currentPublisher) {
            res.status = 301;
            return res.json({
                message:
                    "You must be authenticated as publisher in order to add a game",
            });
        }

        const newGameData = gamesRepository.create({
            ...data,
            poster: posterPath,
            video: videoPath,
            distro: distroPath,
            publisher: currentPublisher,
        });
        const newGame = await gamesRepository.save(newGameData);

        res.status(200);
        return res.json({ message: "Game added", data: newGame });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error creating the game", err);

        res.status(400);
        return res.json({ message: "Error creating the game" });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using just one `multer` instance.

From what I looked at the [docs of multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme), the `upload` function is **not a Promise**. So the `await` function in front of `uploader.upload` method will not work.

What you need is to [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) your upload function. Here's an example:

```js
const util = require('util');

// your code ...
try {
  const promisifiedUploadFunc = util.promisify(uploader.upload);
  const newPath = await promisifiedUploadFunc(posterPath, options);
  // Bug - unlink happens before file uploaded
  await unlink(posterPath);
  posterPath = newPath as string;
} catch (e) {
  // continue code..
}
```